# JavaBeans and sending "double" values

Tags: java, html, jsp, javabeans

im trying to write an HTML page which accepts an argument for amount of inches

After the inches has been submitted a JSP page then invokes a bean which converts this inch amount to centimeters and then returns the output

this is what i have:

HTML page

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Converter</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="QueryResult.jsp">
        <fieldset><legend>Please enter initial measurement</legend>
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>Inches: </td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="inches" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="Submit" value="submit" /></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

the bean i want to use

```
package Module6;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class calculate implements Serializable {

   private double inch;
   private double cm;

   public calculate() {}

   public calculate(double tempInch){
       this.inch = tempInch;               
   }

   public double convert(){
       cm = inch * 2.54;
       return cm;
   }  
}
```

the jsp looks like this

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>JSP Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <%@ page import="Module6.calculate"%>

   <%calculate calc = new calculate();%>

   The result is : <% out.println(calc.convert()); %>

   </body>
</html>
```

The result is always 0.0 ... what am i doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didnt use your `<input type="text" name="inches" />` that is why it is giving 0.

your inch and cm is using its default value which is 0.0 in result = 0.0;

get the value of the input from the previous page.

```
request.getParameter("inches");

calculate calc = new calculate(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("inches"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving your Calculate object a value.  You're using the no argument constructor.

Also, you should follow standard conventions and give your classes names that start with CAPITAL letters.